# MIPS recursive procedure storing on the heap

Tags: recursion, stored-procedures, mips, subroutine

so for the program below, in which you jump back to the loop over and over in a recursive procedure, you would have to store the return address on the heap, but storing it in the same offset would just overwrite the previous one like below:

```
fact:
    sub  $sp, $sp, 8        # make space on the stack for two items
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)        # save the return address on the stack 
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)        # save the argument n on the stack
```

so the first loop would be

```
fact:
    sub  $sp, $sp, 8        # make space on the stack for two items
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)        # save the return address on the stack 
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)        # save the argument n on the stack
```

and then the second loop would also be

```
fact:
    sub  $sp, $sp, 8        # make space on the stack for two items
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)        # save the return address on the stack 
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)        # save the argument n on the stack
```

So wouldn't this just keep overwriting the return address value store on the heap in a recursive function? the full code below for reference:

```
.text
.globl  main
main:                       # main has to be a global label
addu  $s7, $0, $ra      # save return address in global register


.data
.globl  input
input:    .asciiz  "\nEnter N: "
    .text
    li   $v0, 4             # print_str
    la   $a0, input         # takes address of string as argument
    syscall                 #
    li   $v0, 5             # read_int
    syscall                 #
    add  $s1, $0, $v0       # The value of N has been read into $s1
    add  $a0, $0, $s1       # set the parameter to N for fact call
    jal  fact               # Call the factorial function
    add  $s0, $0, $v0       # f = fact(N);

  # OUTPUT THE RESULT
    .data
    .globl  output
output:  .asciiz  "N! = "
newline: .asciiz  "\n"
    .text
    li   $v0, 4             # print_str
    la   $a0, output        # takes address of string as an argument 
    syscall                 # output the label
    li   $v0, 1             # print_int
    add  $a0, $0, $s0       # takes integer
    syscall                 # output f
    li   $v0, 4             # print_str
    la   $a0, newline       #  
    syscall                 # new line
    

  # USUAL STAFF AT THE END OF THE MAIN
    addu $ra, $0, $s7       # restore the return address
    jr   $ra                # return to the main program
    add  $0, $0, $0         # nop (no operation)

    .globl   fact 
fact:
    sub  $sp, $sp, 8        # make space on the stack for two items
    sw   $ra, 4($sp)        # save the return address on the stack 
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)        # save the argument n on the stack 
    slt  $t0, $a0, 1        # test for n &lt; 1
    beq  $t0, $zero, L1     # if (n &gt;= 1) go to L1
    add  $v0, $zero, 1      # otherwise return 1
    add  $sp, $sp, 8        # pop the saved items off stack, no call
    jr   $ra                # and return
L1:
    sub  $a0, $a0, 1        # when n &gt;= 1:  decrement the argument
    jal  fact               # call fact(n-1)
    lw   $a0, 0($sp)        # restore the value of argument n
    lw   $ra, 4($sp)        # restore the return address
    add  $sp, $sp, 8        # release the save area on the stack
    mul  $v0, $a0, $v0      # yes it's a multiply!  (n*fact(n-1))
    jr   $ra                # return
```

I have tried retracing the recursive procedure on pen and paper and couldn't understand how it store value on the heap without overwriting itself.

Comment: _"you would have to store the return address on the heap"_. You mean the _stack_, not the heap. _"but storing it in the same offset would just overwrite the previous one"_ You're not storing it at the same address since you're subtracting 8 from the stack pointer before each pair of stores (assuming that you have no bugs related to this elsewhere; I didn't look at the rest of the code).

Comment: Looks like you forgot to account for the `sub $sp, $sp, 8` and `add $sp, $sp, 8` in  your tracing on pen and paper. Since the address held in `$sp` changes, the *same offset* refers to a *new memory address*. Each invocation effectively creates its own stack frame, and yes, the offsets are the same so *the shape: size and layout of the stack frame* is the same, but each stack frame occupies its own and *different memory* on the stack.

Comment: Address computation is unsigned, so when doing that use unsigned addition/subtraction. While you won't see any address computation in the C version of factorial, in assembly it is allocating stack space, which is address computation. Thus, should be using `subu $sp, $sp, 8` and `addu $sp, $sp, 8`. The difference being that the `addu`/`subu` instruction will not check for signed arithmetic overflow, whereas the `add`/`sub` instructions will — and this check, for signed overflow, is a logic error when done for address computation.